# Nginx reverse proxy in docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have these containers in my server with their respective networks:

- nginx reverse proxy (network ?)
- web for app1 (network app1-net)
- db for app1 (network app1-net)
- web for app2 (network app2-net)
- db for app2 (network app2-net)

I want nginx to work as proxy for the two web apps, but I don't know how to get this working, because they are not in the same network so I can't write something like:

`proxy_pass http://webapp1;`

And I cannot use localhost either.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about having your nginx on both app1-net and app2-net? See [this article on Multiple Docker Networks](https://success.docker.com/article/multiple-docker-networks)

Comment: @DanN Thank you! That solves it :) I didn't even know I could attach docker containers to multiple networks